# Django template 'url' filter encodes a substitution string

Tags: django, django-templates, sendgrid, django-template-filters

Using django1.9

my urls would look something like example.com/my_url/cachebuster

in my email.html template I have something like

```
{% url my_url cachebuster %}
```

Now cachebuster is actually "%%cachebuster%%"
This is a substitution string which my email api is parsing for, and whenever it finds "%%cachebuster%%" it replaces it with the specific users cachebuster.

My issue is that the django {% url %} function automatically encodes that string to "%25%25cachebuster%25%25"

Which means the api never finds "%%cachebuster%%" and never replaces it

So instead of a dynamic url, its always example.com/my_url/%25%25cachebuster%25%25

How can I fix this, without changing the substitution string? I've tried using mark_safe but haven't got it to work

The only way I can think of is to hardcode /my_url/{{cachebuster}} without using the django url tag, but this is bad practice because the url templatetag was created for a reason

Comment: Yes, `url` tag was created for a reason but it is meant to generate valid Django URLs while you want to generate an _invalid_ URL. You can either write your own tag library, or hardcode as you already suggested.

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is actually being encoded, and not just being displayed like that in your browser?

Comment: The `url` tag is created to make reversing urls for named views easier. Hence I don't think it's a bad practice to do `{% url my_url %}{{ cache_buster}}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, since {{ cachebuster }} by itself works fine